# pointers and char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I think that this is a fairly simple question... I've tried finding the specifics and can't. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char * veggie_burger = "delicious";
    cout<<endl<<veggie_burger<<endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < 9; count++){
        cout<<veggie_burger[count]
            <<" @: "
            <<&veggie_burger[count]
            <<endl;
    }
    cout<<&veggie_burger;

    return 0;   
}
```

this will output

> delicious
>  d @ delicious
>  e @ elicious
>  l @ licious
>  i @
>   icious
>  c @ cious
>  i @ ious
>  o @ ous
>  u @ us
>  s @ s
>  001DF7D4 (or wherever)]

What exactly is the difference between `&veggie_burger[n]` and `&veggie_burger`? Shouldn't the pointer be pointing to the place in memory where `&veggie_burger[3]` stores 'l' and not start the sequence of characters at 'l'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`veggie_burger[n]` is exactly the same as `*(veggie_burger+n)`, so `&veggie_burger[n]` means `veggie_burger + n`, or a pointer to the `n`th character.  It has type `char*`, because it is the address of a character.

`&veggie_burger`, on the other hand, is the address of the pointer.  It has type `char **`.

Answer (score 2):

In that case `&veggie_burger` is of type `char **`, it has the address of the pointer. In other words, the pointer's location in memory.

`&veggie_burger[n]` is the address of the n'th member of the array. Not its value.

Do not confuse a pointer with an array. For example:

```
char veggie_burger[] = "delicious";
```

This is an array, and `veggie_burger` == `&veggie_burger` == `&veggie_burger[0]`

Comment: Where's the `const` come from?, and no, `&veggie_burger` is not the same as `&veggie_burger[0]`, even in the array case.

Comment: `veggie_burger` is not `const char*`, is it?

Comment: You are right on that. But about the `&array[0] == &array` i am pretty sure I am correct.

Comment: They are not the same, much as in `char *p; void *p2 = p;` the variables `p` and `p2` are not interchangeable.  Consider `template<typename T> constexpr size_t target_size(const T& p) { return sizeof *p; }`  Now `target_size(&array[0])` and `target_size(&array)` give different results.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
char * veggie_burger = "delicious";
```

is a bad idea and most deprecated; use instead:

```
const char * veggie_burger = "delicious";
```

`&veggie_burger` is just an address of `veggie_burger`; it has nothing to do with the string literal pointed by it.

`&veggie_burger[n]` has two part in it, first `veggie_burger[n]`; which is evaluated as `nth` element of the string literal. 2nd  is `&<element>`, which means address of the `nth` element.

Having said that `&veggie_burger[3]` stores the address at letter `l`. i.e

```
&veggie_burger[3] ==> (veggie_burger + 3)
```

Comment: cool thanks, I'm still fairly new... Noted on the bad idea also, perhaps it's off topic from the original question, but why is it most deprecated?

Comment: @Dave, I meant **mostly** :). Because `"delicious"` (when used as string literal and not an array) is stored in **read-only** region. So pointer to it also should be read-only (i.e. `const char*`). It's not off topic; if you accidently modify it say `veggie_burger[3] = 'a';` then it results in undefined behavior or crash. So always make sure that you make these `const char*`. Also note that this is valid (as it's array): `char veggie[] = "delicious";`

Answer (score 0):

When you send a `char *` to `cout`, the compiler recognizes that and the string is printed.  When you send a `char **` to `cout`, the numeric address of the `char *` is printed.

Since `&veggie_burger` is a `char **`, you get the address, whereas with `&veggie_burger[3]` you get a string (the remainder after skipping ahead 3 bytes).